# Can I "return" Num a just like literals seem to be able to "return" Num a?

Tags: haskell

In ghci, if I do

```hs
Prelude> :t 5
Prelude> 5 :: Num a => a
```

But if I assign 5, I get `Integer` as the type:

```hs
Prelude> let f = 5
Prelude> t: f
Prelude> f :: Integer
```

From my understanding, the fact that 5 is `Num a => a` allows is to sit in any mathematical expression happily (such as `5 + 5.0`). I guess I'm curious if this is Haskell magic, or whether I can make a variable `f` that behave the same way, so that I can do `f + 5.0`. I've tried the following with no luck:

```hs
let f = 10 :: Num a => a
```

`f + 5.0` still gives me an error.

Comment: It's the "dreaded" monomorphism restriction that makes `f` have type `Integer` in your first example. I'm surprised the explicit polymorphic type doesn't work, but I can't check right now.

Comment: @RobinZigmond You need to give the type to `f`, not its definition to work. `let f :: Num a => a ; f = 10`. Otherwise, you are giving `10` its own type, which is a no-op -- later on it will still be instantiated following the DMR.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @chi, that makes sense, I don't think I realised that the annotation was given to the literal `10` rather than the variable `f`.